# "Invalid use of group function" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

Using MySQL, my database looks like this:

```
+-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+
|      moviesInfo       |                    |      |        |
+-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+
| title                 | director           | year | oscars |
+-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+
| BoBoiBoy: The Movie   | Nizam Razak        | 2016 | 0      |
| Inception             | Christopher Nolan  | 2010 | 4      |
| Interstellar          | Christopher Nolan  | 2014 | 1      |
| Munna Bhai M.B.B.S.   | Rajkumar Hirani    | 2003 | 0      |
| My Dear Brother       | Ertem Egilmez      | 1973 | 0      |
| Rocky                 | John G. Avildsen   | 1976 | 3      |
| The Nights of Cabiria | Federico Fellini   | 1957 | 1      |
| The Sixth Sense       | M. Night Shyamalan | 1999 | 6      |
| Tokyo Story           | Yasujirô Ozu       | 1953 | 0      |
| Yojimbo               | Akira Kurosawa     | 1961 | 1      |
+-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+


select director from moviesInfo
where MAX(year) > 2000 and SUM(oscars) > 2
group by director;
```

With the above query I try to get the director who has a movie later than the year 2000 and has more than 2 oscars, but I get an error

```
Invalid use of group function
```

Being still new to MySQL I don't fully understand this.

**Expected** **output** would be

```
+-------------------+
|     director      |
+-------------------+
| Christopher Nolan |
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html) cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause. They should stay in the `HAVING` clause, after the `GROUP BY` because they operate on the sets of values generated by grouping.

Your query should be:

```
SELECT director 
FROM moviesInfo
GROUP BY director
HAVING MAX(year) > 2000 AND SUM(oscars) > 2
```

### Update

On OP's request, this is, roughly, how the above SQL query is executed:

1. The `GROUP BY` clause tell the server to group the matching rows (all rows 
   because there is no `WHERE` clause to filter them). The groups are as follows:

   ```
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+
   | title                 | director           | year | oscars |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+
   | BoBoiBoy: The Movie   | Nizam Razak        | 2016 | 0      |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+
   | Inception             | Christopher Nolan  | 2010 | 4      |
   | Interstellar          | Christopher Nolan  | 2014 | 1      |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+
   | Munna Bhai M.B.B.S.   | Rajkumar Hirani    | 2003 | 0      |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+
   | My Dear Brother       | Ertem Egilmez      | 1973 | 0      |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+
   | Rocky                 | John G. Avildsen   | 1976 | 3      |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+
   | The Nights of Cabiria | Federico Fellini   | 1957 | 1      |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+
   | The Sixth Sense       | M. Night Shyamalan | 1999 | 6      |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+
   | Tokyo Story           | Yasujirô Ozu       | 1953 | 0      |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+
   | Yojimbo               | Akira Kurosawa     | 1961 | 1      |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+
   ```
2. The `HAVING` clause makes it compute `MAX(year)` and `SUM(oscars)` for each group. The data now look like:

   ```
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+-----------+-------------+
   | title                 | director           | year | oscars | MAX(year) | SUM(oscars) |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+-----------+-------------+
   | BoBoiBoy: The Movie   | Nizam Razak        | 2016 | 0      | 2016      | 0           |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+-----------+-------------+
   | Inception             | Christopher Nolan  | 2010 | 4      | 2014      | 5           |
   | Interstellar          | Christopher Nolan  | 2014 | 1      |           |             |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+-----------+-------------+
   | Munna Bhai M.B.B.S.   | Rajkumar Hirani    | 2003 | 0      | 2003      | 0           |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+-----------+-------------+
   | My Dear Brother       | Ertem Egilmez      | 1973 | 0      | 1973      | 0           |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+-----------+-------------+
   | Rocky                 | John G. Avildsen   | 1976 | 3      | 1976      | 3           |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+-----------+-------------+
   | The Nights of Cabiria | Federico Fellini   | 1957 | 1      | 1957      | 1           |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+-----------+-------------+
   | The Sixth Sense       | M. Night Shyamalan | 1999 | 6      | 1999      | 6           |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+-----------+-------------+
   | Tokyo Story           | Yasujirô Ozu       | 1953 | 0      | 1953      | 0           |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+-----------+-------------+
   | Yojimbo               | Akira Kurosawa     | 1961 | 1      | 1961      | 1           |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+-----------+-------------+
   ```
3. Next, the conditions on `HAVING` are evaluated and the data set looks like:

   ```
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+-----------+-------------+
   | title                 | director           | year | oscars | MAX(year) | SUM(oscars) |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+-----------+-------------+
   | Inception             | Christopher Nolan  | 2010 | 4      | 2014      | 5           |
   | Interstellar          | Christopher Nolan  | 2014 | 1      |           |             |
   +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------+-----------+-------------+
   ```
4. Now the `SELECT` clause is used to generate the result set you expect.

*Please note that the explanation above is the theoretical model behind the `GROUP BY` queries. In the real world, MySQL (and the other RDBMSes) mixes and runs the above steps in a different order. It combines the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses (if possible), processes one row at a time and tries to filter out as many rows as possible as soon as possible, in order to finish the processing as quickly as possible.*

#### Remarks

The `SELECT` clause on a `GROUP BY` query [can contain only expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) that:

1. are also present in the `GROUP BY` clause;
   for example, `director`;
2. are [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html);
   for example `SUM(oscars)`, `COUNT(*)`, `AVG(year)` etc. There is no requirement for them to be present in other clauses;
3. are functionally dependent on columns that are present in the `GROUP BY` clause;
   for example, if the `GROUP BY` clause contains a column that is the `PK` of a table, any column of that table is allowed in the `SELECT` clause because all the rows present in a group will have the same value for all columns of that table.

Let's remark that the columns `title`, `year` and `oscars` cannot be in the `SELECT` clause because the do not match any of the above conditions. Adding them to the `SELECT` clause produces invalid SQL. The reason is obvious: there are two distinct values for `title` in the second group. Which one to choose?

Before version 5.7.5, MySQL used to accept such invalid SQL queries but it reserved its right to [return indeterminate results](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). This means the result can change if the query is executed against the same data set on a different machine (or after the data is restored from backup).

Since version 5.7.5, MySQL rejects invalid `GROUP BY` queries.

Comment: Thanks, can you maybe explain what the `HAVING` clause do.

Comment: @Ludisposed `HAVING` is somewhat like `WHERE` except that it operates on the groups formed instead of every record.  His HAVING clause is saying where a director's group of records has a year past 2000 and its total sum of oscars is more than 2.

Comment: Excellent explenation, I feel sad I cannot upvote twice now.